# SQL Join two query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

[image][image]

[image]

I need some help combining these two queries so I can get this in one single view.

Query 1

```
select t.*, n.caption, n.description
from (
    select NodeID, 
              count(distinct cpuindex) as number_of_cpu, 
                case 
                           When count(distinct cpuindex) < 8 THEN 1
                           Else count(distinct cpuindex)/8 
                           End AS number_of_cores
    from CPUMultiLoad_Detail (nolock) where nodeid in (select nodeid from nodesdata)
       group by NodeID
   ) as t
inner join NodesData as n (nolock) on n.nodeid = t.nodeid
where n.description NOT Like '%Windows%'
order by n.description
```

Query 2

```
SELECT D.Environment, B.Name, C.Caption, A.ComponentStatisticData, A.ErrorMessage
FROM [APM_CurrentStatistics] A, APM_Application B, NodesData C
join NodesCustomProperties D on D.NodeID= C.NodeID
WHERE 
A.ApplicationID=B.ID AND
A.NodeID=C.NodeID AND 
B.Name IN ('Oracle Database Licensing')
```

I want to join first query and second query so I have CPU Information and Licensing Information in same table. How do I join both query? We can use common key Nodes.NodeID to join and not sure how. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit joins, it's a mess. Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "How do I join both query?" - please show some sample data and expected results because its unclear as asked.

Comment: Hi Dale, I have added screenshots.The caption is the server name on each row which is identified by the node id. Each row has one node id.

Comment: @SQLNovice you still haven't showed the most important part - what you want to see once they are combined.

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN` would be a good start.  It's been around for over 25 years!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider joining the inner aggregate subquery of first query which holds distinct *NodeID* to the second query using a CTE. Additionally, use [explicit `JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)(current standard in SQL) and heed [bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) and use more informative table aliases.

```
WITH agg AS 
   (
    select NodeID, 
           count(distinct cpuindex) as number_of_cpu, 
           case 
               when count(distinct cpuindex) < 8 THEN 1
               else count(distinct cpuindex) / 8 
           end AS number_of_cores
    from CPUMultiLoad_Detail 
    where nodeid in (select nodeid from nodesdata)
    group by NodeID
   )

SELECT cp.Environment, app.Name, n.Caption,
       cs.ComponentStatisticData, cs.ErrorMessage,
       agg.NodeID, agg.number_of_cpu, agg.number_of_cores, n.description
FROM APM_CurrentStatistics cs 
INNER JOIN APM_Application app 
  ON cs.ApplicationID = app.ID
  AND app.Name IN ('Oracle Database Licensing') 
INNER JOIN NodesData n
  ON cs.NodeID = n.NodeID
  AND n.description NOT LIKE '%Windows%'
INNER JOIN NodesCustomProperties cp 
  ON cp.NodeID = n.NodeID
INNER JOIN agg
  ON cs.NodeID = agg.NodeID
ORDER BY n.description
```

Comment: Thank you so much  Parfait, that worked great and what I was looking for. I just need one last change. I need the component Name values "Oracle Version", "Oracle Partitioning", "Real Application Clusters (RAC)" which are currently displayed in rows and repeated for each device show up as a column instead. Is there a way it can be done?

Comment: Forgive me, isn't that asking a new question? Your original post does not mention such a specification. Look into pivoting data using this query as the base source.

Comment: Thank you Parfait, I will give that  a try. I am new to SQL scripting and still learning.